# iPhone: once unlocked, always unlocked?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

I got an iPhone from a telco carrier two years ago, as at that time, I didn't really know whether I bought the phone unlocked or was it locked to that specific carrier.

All I knew was, I change my telco afterwards, and I could use the new telco's data plan and voice and SMS service without trouble.

As I want to travel to overseas soon, I am looking forward to buy local 3G SimCards to satisfy my appetite for Internet surfing. I wonder whether I can do so without performing extra steps on my iPhone?

I think when I managed to change from one carrier to another previously, it indicated the phone was unlocked, at least among local carrier, but I am unsure whether this phone will remain unlocked when I travel overseas? Or is there a possibility that although you can change local carrier, but for you to change to an oversea carrier you would need to do some other steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SIM Unlocked means SIM unlocked. There is no lock, so you're free to go.

Answer (score 0):

if you where able to use another carrier locally or not, with a *different **SIM** card*, you are basically good to go, however if you didn't change your simcard, and simply used another *carriers antennas*, it proves nothing! so you need to test your iPhone with a **new simcard**, from a **different carrier**, different data plans doesn't matter!

second depending on the country you are traveling too you need to check to see if your phone can handle the different *bandwidths* that are used around the world, if you want me to help you, you need to tell me your *phone model*, and the *country* witch you are traveling too!

and you said you bought the phone 2 years ago, most likely you will be able to call your carrier and have them unlock it for you, perhaps for a small fee!